# SoloAmbient and applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, avaudiosession

I want to set SoloAmbient (and silence all music in iPhone) after my application goes to Background.

I wrote such a code, but it doesn't work

**MyAppDelegate.h**

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
AVAudioSession *audioSession;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioSession *audioSession;
```

**MyAppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
NSLog(@"Application entered background state.");

//[self.DelcloseSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:nil];  
//[self.DelcloseSession setActive:YES error:nil];

audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setDelegate:self];

NSError *averr = nil;
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&averr]; 
if(averr)
{
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [averr domain], [averr code], [[averr userInfo] description]);
}

averr = nil;
[audioSession setActive:YES error:&averr];
if(averr)
{
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [averr domain], [averr code], [[averr userInfo] description]);
}

averr = nil;
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:&averr];
if(averr)
{
    NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [averr domain], [averr code], [[averr userInfo] description]);
}
```

In effect app sends me a log "audioSession: NSOSStatusErrorDomain 560161140 (null)" and music on iPhone (from iPod or some other app) is still being played.

How to fix it? How to do, that when app went to Background it opens SoloAmbient and silence everything? Maybe is there any other opportunity to sleep the music?

Answer (score 0):

Your app will need to request audio backgrounding in its background modes plist, set the audio session and start playing the sound (silence, etc.) before resigning active and going into the background.  Otherwise the audio session belongs to the new foreground app.

Comment: Do you mean to move `audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
 [audioSession setDelegate:self];` to  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions? "start playing the sound" what do you mean?

Comment: If an app is not playing a sound, it will not stay running when it goes into the background, which means it will no longer have any say over the audio session type.

Comment: I have a loop that plays 'silent' music to keep app. I either use a session there: `[self.silentSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
        UInt32 doSetProperty = 1;
        AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(doSetProperty), &doSetProperty);
        [self.silentSession setActive:YES error:nil];` but it's not in delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect iPod playback state using the mediaplayer framework

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

and then this

```
if ([[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
    //iPod is playing
} else {
    //iPod is not playing
}
```

and go from there

Comment: But I don't want to stop only iPod. I want to silence each possible music like streaming, music from other apps. That's why I wanted to use SoloAmbient instead of basic stopping the iPod.